# Is there any connected n-manifold such that $H_n(X,Z)=Z\times Z$?

Tags: geometric-topology

I think the question is equal to whether a n-manifold has a n-submanifold which is compact in n-manifold.
I feel there is not such manifold, but I don't know how to prove it.
In fact, I just need some reference about the proof. Thank you.

Comment: What about the disjoint union of two $n$-spheres?

Comment: You might consider reading Hatcher's book: Algebraic Topology available online: http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATpage.html. Chapter 2 should have what you are looking for.

Comment: In response to your first sentence, you may want to consider that any open subset of an n-manifold is an embedded n-submanifold.

Comment: @BrianKlatt   sorry,i am really careless.If assume the manifold is connected and compact and the submanifold must be compact ,how to proof there is not the n-submanifold?Besides,how to compute the open ball's homolopy group,i don't know how to compute the manifold's homolopy group which's triangulation is infinite or is not compact,

Comment: @lanse2pty, any closed $n$-submanifold is clopen.

Comment: Please, if you need to correct anything in the body of the question (and if you are «really being careless», you do need to!) then please do. It is no a good idea to leave corrections hid in comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you assume the manifold to be connected, the answer is not, there aren't such manifolds. For any closed $n$-manifold $M$, we have $H_n(M; \Bbb Z) = \Bbb Z$ if $M$ is orientable, or $H_n(M; \Bbb Z) = 0$ if it is not orientable. If $M$ is not closed then $H_n(M; \Bbb Z) = 0$. This is definitely a special case of Poincar\'e duality, although it follows from the existence of a handlebody decomposition with only one $n$-handle for closed $M$, or without $n$-handles otherwise. You can look at almost any book about homology theory (e.g. Vick), or about differential topology.
Of course, in the disconnected case you can easily construct manifolds which satisfy your condition (take the disjoint union of any two closed, orientable, connected $n$-manifolds), see other comments.

Comment: The question does not assume that manifold is connected. If one allows for the disconnected case, then the answer can be yes as Oscar Randal-Williams points out.

Comment: Ops you're right, thank you! I edited the answer to include the disconnected case.

Comment: sorry,i forget to say it is connected.Are you sure that $H_n(M;Z)=Z_2$if it is not orientable? I think the connected n-manifold's $H_n(M;Z)$is Z or $0$,how does it is $Z_2$?Could you give me a example?

Comment: You right sorry! I corrected the mistake in the non-orientable case.